# Connecting to an mdb file using OdbcConnection in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, oledbconnection

I am trying to connect to an mdb file from C# 2013 using OdbcConnection. I used to have Office 2000 on my Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines, but I have upgraded to Office 2013 on both and it now longer works on either. My database is still in mdb format.

Here's the code:

```
const string myConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Path\Mydb.mdb";
OdbcConnection connRL = new OdbcConnection();
connRL.Open();
```

Whatever I have tried I get the following error:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

I have Installed the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" and the "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" but neither of them have made any difference. I can create a new Data Source from the VS 2013 Project menu and that all works at design time.

When I create a blank udl file and double click on it and go to the provider tab there's nothing listed about Access or Jet, but I can see the providers in the registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VWDExpress\12.0_Config\DataProviders. Why aren't they there?

What else can I do to get this to work? I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Use `OleDbConnection` instead.

Comment: I thought I was, should read my own code!

Comment: Find difference `OleDbConnection vs OdbcConnection`.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can't connect to the `mdb` through `OdbcConnection`. Anyway, to connect to the DB you must specify the connection string on your connection object which is not specified in your code.

To access `mdb` use code like this:

```
const string myConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Path\Mydb.mdb";
using(var connRL = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    //use your connection
}
```

Comment: Yeah that worked I didn't realise I had been using OdbcConnection. I also had to switch to 32-bit in order to use OleDbConnection.